# Correct way to call GetModuleHandle in C and return function pointer

Tags: c, dll, function-pointers

I am calling a DLL from C, but when I call GetProcAddress, GCC says:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

The DLL takes a pointer to a double array and returns a pointer to a double array.  Here is the relevant part of the C code:

```
typedef double* (*dllfunc1)(double*);
double *return_pointer;

hinstLib = LoadLibrary(dllname);
dll_handle = GetModuleHandle(dllname);
return_pointer = (dllfunc1)(GetProcAddress(dll_handle, "Main_Entry_fn"));
```

The final line is the one that fails.  I have tried a number of different permutations, but none has worked.  There is a fair amount of info on the net about typedef prototypes for function pointers, but very few in the context of GetProcAddress to call a DLL function.

When I change the definition of return_pointer to:

```
int return_pointer
```

I get:

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

So it looks like the problem is in the variable "return_pointer."  Most likely it needs to be defined as int and cast to a pointer, but I haven't been able to cast it to a pointer.  The original definition (*double) was because it returns a pointer to a double array.

Where am I going wrong?  Any ideas will be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is `return_pointer` meant to hold the pointer to the function itself, or the pointer that the function returns?  In the code shown, you haven't actually called the function yet.

Comment: (Also, I think you don't need to call LoadLibrary _and_ GetModuleHandle, just one or the other, but I could be wrong about that.)

Comment: It holds the pointer to the function, but I can't call the function until I get the function pointer, and that's where I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your code should be like this:

```
typedef double *(*dllfunc1)(double *);

HANDLE dll_handle = LoadLibrary(dllname);
dllfunc1 Main_Entry_fn = (dllfunc1)(GetProcAddress(dll_handle, "Main_Entry_fn"));

double *result = Main_Entry_fn(argument);
```

`dllfunc1`, which is a pointer-to-function type, is the correct type for the pointer-to-function variable that will hold the pointer returned by `GetProcAddress`.  `double *` is just the type of the pointer returned by `Main_Entry_fn`, so that's the right type for the variable that holds the result of *actually calling* `Main_Entry_fn`.

Also, if I'm reading MSDN correctly, you do not need to call both `LoadLibrary` and `GetModuleHandle`; one or the other is enough.

Also also, it will be less confusing if you name the pointer-to-function after the function you're looking up by name.

Also also also, pointer asterisks bind to the right, so never cuddle them to the left, even if you're writing C++.

Comment: Thanks, zwol.  It works except that it's dllfunc1 return_pointer (no asterisk needed).  Yes, it's true that you don't need to call both.